# Can I create my own successful response in Jasmine node.js?

Tags: node.js, jasmine

I'm wanting to force a test returns failure, bring success, why this?

I am using the proctrator and I need to wait for a data that comes from the server to the screen, however I have to update the page every 1 minute, I could not do something that updates and at the same time wait for the answer, I had to make a "for" execute a promise with loop that repeats 14 times, which gives a total of 14 minutes and every minute it refreshes the page, when it arrives the dice throws me an exception that can end before the loop is over, so that I can move on to the next test .

To not fail in my test, I would like this exception to be true, but I could not put a function in the jasmine to modify it, I have a very simple example of what I would like to do.

```
describe('Start simulator False', () => {
  it('expect a fake to turn true ', () => {
    const addition = 5 + 5;

    expect(addition).toBe(2);
  });
});
```

This expectation that expects 10 instead of 2, I would like instead of seeing a fake would like to see a truth, I know it is wrong but I can create a unique function that only I can use when ignoring its basic logic because I I know it's true and the only alternative I have is this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom equality testers. See the documentation : https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/custom_equality

But i will replace the jasmine equality tester.

So maybe you want to add your own matcher : https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/custom_matcher